# Python How to sliding for sum data in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have data frame like this.

```
df = [3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 3]
```

I want to slice to sum 3 value like this.

```
3+2+4 = 9
2+4+1 = 7
4+1+0 = 5
1+0+3 = 4
```

So, the result will be.

```
9, 7, 5, 4
```

How to for sum dataframe with python ?

Comment: by pandas methods - `df.rolling(3).sum().dropna().iloc[:,0].tolist()`

Comment: @splash58 not quite... `df` here appears to be a list (bit of a confusing name) - it should be at least a `Series`, so probably: `pd.Series(df).rolling(3).dropna().astype(int).tolist()` is probably closer (depending on whether the complete rolling window result will actually fit as an `int` with NaN's dropped)

Comment: Last sentence says "dataframe". So I think we can assume this is a dataframe/series. Maybe OP didn't know how to properly format it in the question

Comment: If one of the answers has helped you solve your problem, it's [good practice to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you're going to use, especially when a number of people took the time to propose solutions to your problem. If they haven't, please can you clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a sliding slice in a list comprehension

```
df = [3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 3]
print([sum(df[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(df)-2)])
```

```
[9, 7, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
a = map(lambda x: sum(df[x:x+3]),range(len(df)-2))
print(list(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

your `df` isn't dataframe. It is the list. You may use generator expression with `np.roll`

```
n = 3
a = np.array(df)
sum(np.roll(a, -x) for x in range(n))[:len(a)-n+1]

Out[29]: array([9, 7, 5, 4])
```